# How to accept input from user in oracle xe 11g (Accept x prompt '...' )?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I try to use this small SQL code in Oracle XE 11g:

```
ACCEPT name PROMPT 'Your name:'

BEGIN

    dbms_output.put_line('Hello ' || '&name');

END;
```

And I get this error:

> ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Comment: This code syntactically and semantically correct. Should run without errors. The only thing is, there is an unprintable symbol between `name` and `PROMPT`, some clients may interpret it incorrectly.

Comment: Where did you run it?

Comment: Are you using sqlplus or SQL Developer? Or maybe other tool?

Comment: I am using Oracle XE 11g(running in opera) and within SQL Workshop the SQL Commands tab.

Comment: `accept` is not a SQL statement. It is a utility command supported only by SQ\*Plus and SQL Developer. You cannot use it anywhere else. Also: there is not such thing as "the sql command tab" in "Oracle 11g XE" - the Oracle database does not have a UI - are you maybe talking about the interface in the browser? That APEX based "UI" has so many limitations you should stop using that. Get SQL Developer and use that (or any other decent SQL client)

Comment: Accepting input from a user is pretty much half the reason you would build an Apex application. Create a simple application, add a page with an item and a "submit" button. You can then add a Process that will run PL/SQL to process whatever the user enters into the item.